# google.language API is no longer available

Tags: javascript, google-translate, transliteration, google-language-api

I have been using below posted code for transliterating user input on button click. But when run the code and click the transliterate button, I am getting  `/* callback */google.language.callbacks.id100('22', null, 403, 'This API is no longer available.', 200)` response in my browser's (firefox) console. So please tell what can be its alternate solution?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 
    <title>Google AJAX Language API - Basic Transliteration</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    google.load("language", "1");
    google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });
    function intialize_transliteration(){
        var options = {
          sourceLanguage: 'en', 
          destinationLanguage: ['kn'], 
          shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
          transliterationEnabled: true
        };
        var control =
            new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    //add as many as required
        var ids = [ "fnk", "lnk" ];

    control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
        control.showControl('translControl');
    }   

   google.setOnLoadCallback(intialize_transliteration);


    function tr() { 
            //Call google.language.transliterate() 
            google.language.transliterate(["asdas"], "en", "ur", function(result) {

                var container = document.getElementById("fnk");
                if (result.transliterations && result.transliterations.length > 0 &&
                    result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords.length > 0) {
                  container.innerHTML = result.transliterations[0].transliteratedWords[0];
                }

            });
        }


    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
 <br>      First Name <input value="Thejesh Gangaiah" id="fn" />
 <br>      First Name (in Kannada) <input value="" id="fnk"/>
 <br>      Last Name <input value="Nagarathna" id="ln" />
 <br>      Last Name (in Kannada) <input value="" id="lnk"/>

 <div id='translControl'></div>
<input type="button" onclick="tr()" value="transliterate"/>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The google transliteration API was [deprecated in 2011](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/), so I think that, as of today (June 2018), according to their [Deprecation Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/deprecation), it can be gone. That means that can't be used anymore. The problem is not with your code, but with the service becoming unavailable.

Comment: There is no alternative other than completely rewriting the code and/or using a different service. There have been seven years since it got deprecated, which should have been used for finding alternatives. This is the current system that could solve this problem: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/

Comment: Please, accept the answer if this was what you were looking for.